# Regular Expressions Insight in R

Tags: r, regex

Suppose I have a string:

```
string = "VNYTQAKENGSD"
```

And I need to find the positions where this expression holds.

N{P}[ST]{P} (Meaning 4 letters, [N,¬P,S or T, ¬P]

The output would be

```
2 9
```

because at position 2 you have `NYTQ` and at 9 `NGSD`

How to write this in regular expressions?

consider `regex` as the regular expressiom

```
 for(i in 1:nchar(string)){

 # If regex is equal to the substring of REGEX, get index.
   if(regex == substr(string, 1, nchar(regex))){
   vector = c(vector,i)
   } 

 #Reduce String
 string = substring(string,2)
 }
```

Please help

Comment: Could you explain your requirement? Find `N`, then any char but `P`, then `S` or `T`, and any char but `P`? Something like [`N[^P][ST][^P]`](https://regex101.com/r/06KuuS/1)? Or do you mean to only match *letters*? Like [`N[A-OQ-Z][ST][A-OQ-Z]`](https://regex101.com/r/06KuuS/2)?

Comment: Yeah its like second option.. Thanks for the link, ill take a look.

Comment: Without any details, only you could answer the question correctly and thus I linked to the answer that helped you find more details on character classes. Now, your question is clear, and I will reopen.

Comment: I edited it, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After clarification, it is clear you need a regex like

```
N[A-OQ-Z][ST][A-OQ-Z]
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/06KuuS/2)

**Details**:

- `N` - matches 1 occurrence of `N`
- `[A-OQ-Z]` - a character class that matches 1 ASCII uppercase letter from `A` till `O` and from `Q` to `Z`
- `[ST]` -  a character class that matches either `S` or `T`
- `[A-OQ-Z]` - ibid.

See more information on [**character classes**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) at regular-expressions.info.

In R (see [online demo](https://ideone.com/LJR911)):

```
string <- "VNYTQAKENGSD"
z <- gregexpr("N[A-OQ-Z][ST][A-OQ-Z]", string)
z[[1]][1:length(z[[1]])]
## => [1] 2 9
```

Comment: Well thank you, this was more than insightful!
I was just about to try it with a loop. I was testing weather it is True or False.
`grep("N[A-OQ-Z][ST][A-OQ-Z]","NASA")`

Comment: Well I cant ignore the attribute,

> string = "VNYTQAKENGSD"
> gregexpr("N[A-OQ-Z][ST][A-OQ-Z]", string)[[1]]
[1] 2 9
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 4 4
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE

Comment: You mean you want to output just the two indices?

Comment: Yes, at some point it was working, but after trying to pass it on a loop to apply it in different strings, it keeps giving me the attributes aswell. And [[]] is not helping me get the first vector of the list. And now the same code you wrote, is giving me the attributes everytime.

Comment: Nevermind, this worked! unlist(grep("N[A-OQ-Z][ST][A-OQ-Z]","NASA"))

Comment: I added a `gregexpr` way.

Comment: Thank you very much